# accessing vector elements when passed using template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I want to print the elements of the vector. The following is my code.

[image: This is my code]

After searching I found the following code and its working:

```
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
```

But can't we use iterators to access the elements? if possible, how?

Comment: instead of linking to an (external) image, please include the code in your question.

Comment: The error tells you what you need to do to fix it.  You could also just use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: hackerrank is not a good place to learn C++

Answer (score 3):

`typename` is missing:

```
template <typename T>
void printArray(const std::vector<T>& a)
{
    for (typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In c++11, you may simply wrote:

```
template <typename T>
void printArray(const std::vector<T>& a)
{
    for (const auto& e : a) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to say why typename is needed.  Not saying you have to as the compiler told him why already.

Comment: Oh dupe closing it would work.  I keep forgetting about that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `auto it = vec.begin()` in case you're using C++11 so you don't really need to worry about the type of `it`.

Comment: In c++11, just use ranged for : (`for (const auto& e : a)`)